# VueJs push array into array values only

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have multiple input that I wish to pass into my form variable but the result is array into array which isn't what i need.

## Samples

> All parts are commented so you won't get confused.

**This is what I have now:**

```
array:2 [
  "form" => array:10 [
    "name" => "tjuhr"
    "link_id" => 5
    "description" => null
    "position" => "Kabel Duct (tanah)"
    "cable_id_id" => null
    "images" => []
    // this is the way currently my cores are returning but i need it changed.
    "cores" => array:1 [
      0 => array:2 [
        0 => array:2 [
          "old_core_id" => 3
          "new_core_id" => 11
        ]
        1 => array:2 [
          "old_core_id" => 5
          "new_core_id" => 20
        ]
      ]
    ]
    "longitude" => "45"
    "latitude" => "4"
    "cable_id" => 2
  ]
  // this part below is for testing purpose only (it has to be pushed into form.cores)
  "cores" => array:2 [
    0 => array:2 [
      "old_core_id" => 3
      "new_core_id" => 11
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      "old_core_id" => 5
      "new_core_id" => 20
    ]
  ]
]
```

**This is what i'm looking for to have**

```
array:2 [
  "form" => array:10 [
    "name" => "tjuhr"
    "link_id" => 5
    "description" => null
    "position" => "Kabel Duct (tanah)"
    "cable_id_id" => null
    "images" => []
    // this is how i need my selected ids return.
    "cores" => array:4 [
      0 => 3
      1 => 11
      2 => 5
      3 => 20
    ]
    "longitude" => "45"
    "latitude" => "4"
    "cable_id" => 2
  ]
]
```

## Code

`Template`

```
<el-dialog title="Add New Titik Closure" :visible.sync="dialogFormVisible">
    <el-form ref="form" :model="form" :label-width="formLabelWidth">
        <el-row :gutter="10">
            <el-col :span="12">
                <el-form-item label="Name">
                    <el-input v-model="form.name"></el-input>
                </el-form-item>
            </el-col>

            <el-col :span="12">
                <el-form-item label="Link">
                    <el-select style="width: 100%;" filterable clearable v-model="form.link_id" placeholder="Select Link">
                        <el-option
                        v-for="link in links"
                        :key="link.id"
                        :label="link.site_name"
                        :value="link.id">
                            <span style="float: left">
                                {{ link.site_name }}
                            </span>
                        </el-option>
                    </el-select>
                </el-form-item>
            </el-col>
        </el-row>

        <el-row :gutter="10">
            <el-col :span="12">
                <el-form-item label="Position">
                    <el-select v-model="form.position" style="width: 100%;" placeholder="Please select Kable Position">
                        <el-option
                            v-for="position in positions"
                            :key="position.value"
                            :label="position.label"
                            :value="position.value">
                            </el-option>
                    </el-select>
                </el-form-item>
            </el-col>

            <el-col :span="12">
                <el-form-item label="Cable">
                    <el-select style="width: 100%;" filterable clearable v-model="form.cable_id" placeholder="Select Cable">
                        <el-option
                        v-for="cable in cables"
                        :key="cable.id"
                        :label="cable.name"
                        :value="cable.id">
                            <span style="float: left">
                                {{ cable.name }}
                            </span>
                        </el-option>
                    </el-select>
                </el-form-item>
            </el-col>

            <el-col :span="12">
                <el-form-item label="Longitude">
                    <el-input v-model="form.longitude"></el-input>
                </el-form-item>
            </el-col>
            <el-col :span="12">
                <el-form-item label="Latitude">
                    <el-input v-model="form.latitude"></el-input>
                </el-form-item>
            </el-col>
        </el-row>

        <!-- add button for multiple input -->
        <el-row :gutter="10">
            <el-col :size="24">
                <div v-for="(indexx, b) in variationChilds" :key="b">
                    <!-- child's -->
                    <el-col :span="6">
                        <el-form-item label="From Tube">
                            <el-select @change="fromTubeHandleChange" v-model="closureForm.fromTube" style="width: 100%;" placeholder="Please select Kable Position">
                                <el-option
                                    v-for="tube in fromTube"
                                    :key="tube.id"
                                    :label="tube.name"
                                    :value="tube.id">
                                    </el-option>
                            </el-select>
                        </el-form-item>
                    </el-col>
                    <el-col :span="6">
                        <el-form-item label="From Core">
                            <el-select style="width: 100%;" filterable clearable v-model="indexx.old_core_id" placeholder="Select From Core">
                                <el-option
                                v-for="core in fromCors"
                                :key="core.id"
                                :label="core.name"
                                :value="core.id">
                                    <span style="float: left">
                                        {{ core.name }}
                                    </span>
                                </el-option>
                            </el-select>
                        </el-form-item>
                    </el-col>

                    <el-col :span="6">
                        <el-form-item label="To Tube">
                            <el-select @change="toTubeHandleChange" style="width: 100%;" filterable clearable v-model="closureForm.toTube" placeholder="Select Cable">
                                <el-option
                                v-for="tubee in toTube"
                                :key="tubee.id"
                                :label="tubee.name"
                                :value="tubee.id">
                                    <span style="float: left">
                                        {{ tubee.name }}
                                    </span>
                                </el-option>
                            </el-select>
                        </el-form-item>
                    </el-col>
                    <el-col :span="6">
                        <el-form-item label="To Core">
                            <el-select style="width: 100%;" filterable clearable v-model="indexx.new_core_id" placeholder="Select To Core">
                                <el-option
                                v-for="coree in toCores"
                                :key="coree.id"
                                :label="coree.name"
                                :value="coree.id">
                                    <span style="float: left">
                                        {{ coree.name }}
                                    </span>
                                </el-option>
                            </el-select>
                        </el-form-item>
                    </el-col>

                    <el-button slot="append"  @click="addChild(b)"  type="success" icon="el-icon-plus"></el-button>
                    <el-button slot="append" @click="removeChild(b)" v-show="b || ( !b == variationChilds.lenghth > 1)" type="danger" icon="el-icon-delete"></el-button>
                </div>
            </el-col>
        </el-row>

        <el-row :gutter="10">
            <el-col :span="24">
                <el-form-item label="Description">
                    <el-input
                        autosize
                        type="textarea"
                        :rows="2"
                        placeholder="Please input your description here."
                        v-model="form.description">
                    </el-input>
                </el-form-item>
            </el-col>
        </el-row>

        <el-row :gutter="10">
            <el-col :span="24">
                <el-form-item label="Gallery">
                    <el-col :span="10">
                        <el-upload
                            class="upload-demo"
                            drag
                            action="/api/upload/singleClosure"
                            :on-exceed="handleExceed"
                            :on-remove="handleRemove"
                            :on-preview="handlePictureCardPreview"
                            :on-success="handleGallerySuccess"
                            :before-remove="beforeRemove"
                            :limit="10"
                            v-model="form.images"
                            multiple>
                            <i class="el-icon-upload"></i>
                            <div class="el-upload__text">Drop file here or <em>click to upload</em></div>
                            <div class="el-upload__tip" slot="tip">jpg/png files. <br> Maximun 10 images.</div>
                        </el-upload>
                    </el-col>
                </el-form-item>
            </el-col>
        </el-row>
    </el-form>
    <span slot="footer" class="dialog-footer">
        <el-button @click="dialogFormVisible = false">Cancel</el-button>
        <el-button type="primary" @click="onSubmit">Confirm</el-button>
    </span>
</el-dialog>
```

`Script`

```
data() {
    return {
        variationChilds: [
            {
                old_core_id: '',
                new_core_id: ''
            }
        ],
        form: {
                name: '',
                link_id: '',
                description: '',
                position: '',
                cable_id_id: '',
                images: [],
                cores: [],
                longitude: '',
                latitude: '',
        },
    }
},
methods: {
    // add core child
    addChild(index){
        this.variationChilds.push({
            old_core_id: '',
            new_core_id: ''
        });
    },
    // remove cores child
    removeChild(index){
        this.variationChilds.splice(index, 1);
    },
    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.form.cores.push(this.variationChilds); // this how i currently push my data into form.cores
        axios.post('/api/admin/closures', {
            form: this.form,
            cores: this.variationChilds // this part below is for testing purpose only (it has to be pushed into form.cores)
        })
        .then(res => {
            this.$notify({
                title: 'Hooray!',
                message: res.data.message,
                offset: 100,
                type: 'message'
            });

            this.dialogFormVisible = false
            this.form = {
                name: '',
                link_id: '',
                description: '',
                cable_id: '',
                position: '',
                longitude: '',
                images: [],
                cores: [],
                latitude: '',
            };

        })
        .catch(error => {
            var errors = error.response.data;
                let errorsHtml = '<ol>';
                $.each(errors.errors,function (k,v) {
                        errorsHtml += '<li>'+ v + '</li>';
                });
                errorsHtml += '</ol>';

            this.$notify.error({
                title: 'Error',
                dangerouslyUseHTMLString: true,
                message: errorsHtml
            });
        })
    },
}
```

`Screenshot`

This is how my form looks like:

[image: one]

## Question

How can I push my data into `form.cores` as i showed in my second sample code?

## Update

I have made some changes (probably not the best solution) but it gives me the result + small issue :)

So I basically changed push in my function to this code:

```
const valObj = this.variationChilds.map(function(elem){
    return elem.old_core_id;
});
const valObj2 = this.variationChilds.map(function(elem){
    return elem.new_core_id;
});
if(valObj.length > 0)
{
    for (let i = 0; i < valObj.length; i++)
    {
        for (let i = 0; i < valObj2.length; i++)
        {
            this.form.cores.push(valObj[i], valObj2[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

now it gives me this result

[image: two]

The problem with this is that I get my values twice (marked as Extra in screenshot).

Comment: Nobody has any idea? :/

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: If you want to loop through elements in an Array without returning an array of the same size, you can use a forEach method to define your custom function. In your case,

```
this.variationChilds.forEach(el => {
  this.form.cores.push(el.old_core_id);
  this.form.cores.push(el.new_core_id);
})
```

should do the trick.

Original Answer: VariationChilds is an array, and you're pushing the entire array as one element into your form.cores array, causing your problem.

```
this.form.cores.push(this.variationChilds); // [].push([{old_core, new_core},{old_core,new_core}]
```

If you want a copy of variationChilds as the value for form.cores, use `this.form.cores = this.variationChilds.slice()`. Alternatively, use a spread operator to push every contained element separately to the new array `this.form.cores.push(...this.variationChilds)`

Or, depending on your use case, you could simply push a new entity directly to this.form.cores instead of having the extra layer in between.

Comment: thank you, I'll try this and let you know if works.

Comment: I've tried your codes (both of them) they return data such as `"cores" => array:2 [
      0 => array:2 [
        "old_core_id" => 13
        "new_core_id" => 4
      ]
      1 => array:2 [
        "old_core_id" => 9
        "new_core_id" => 7
      ]
    ]`  what i'm looking for is `"cores" => array:4 [
      0 => 3
      1 => 11
      2 => 5
      3 => 20
    ]` so there will be no `old_core_id` or `new_core_id`

Comment: I have no idea what the different numbers are from your explanation. Assuming they're the value of new_core_id: `this.form.cores = this.variationChilds.map(x => x.new_core_id)`. 

You can use Array.map with a callback function to return a new array with elements that are dervied from, but not the same as, the elements from the original array.

Comment: ok see the way i store data in my database is `sync()` so i need to only send id's to backend without any names such as `old_core_id` etc.

Comment: I just updated my question would you mind check it?

Comment: I vote up because it does the trick but in case i select wrong option and change it, then i have multiple data. is there a way to avoid pushing each time i select option and just push latest selected options? something like `.bind()` in JavaScript?

Comment: bind() exists in javascript but is irrelevant to this problem. Where are you pushing the data to your form.cores array, because I assumed you do it in your onSubmit function as in your question example?

Comment: yes i push them in `onSubmit` here is screenshot of how my code looks like now https://ibb.co/d5MCX9R

Comment: Then the problem is in your template where you 'v-model' the fields to your variableChilds. Instead of `v-model="indexx.old_core_id"` try `v-model="variableChilds[b].old_core_id"`. I've had trouble with assigning directly to the iterator in the past.

You may want to edit your 'addChild' function to push an empty object and set the properties with Vue's this.$set function because Vue's reactivity system can't track newly added properties to objects. `addChild() { const newItem = {}; this.$set(newItem, 'old_core_id': null); this.variableChilds.push(newItem);}`

Comment: would you check this screenshot please? tried to show differences between your code and mine regarding to your comment https://ibb.co/QjryGvj

Comment: my mistake: it should be `this.$set(newItem, 'old_core_id', null);`. and the same for new_core_id or any other property you have to add.

Comment: you mean something like this? `addChild(index) {
                const newItem = {};
                this.$set(newItem,'old_core_id', null);
                this.$set(newItem,'new_core_id', null);
                this.variationChilds.push(newItem);
            },`

Comment: yes, try it out (though you're not using your index parameter)

Comment: with code above i sent in comment i get this result `"cores" => array:8 [
    0 => 6
    1 => 2
    2 => 4
    3 => 8
    4 => 6
    5 => 2
    6 => 7
    7 => 5
  ]` i should only get `"cores" => array:8 [
    0 => 6
    1 => 2
    2 => 7
    3 => 5
  ]`

Comment: in case my comment was confusing here is screenshot :) https://ibb.co/5GSsTTg